# notepad++ user defined background colour

Tags: notepad++

I'm trying to use a custom syntax highlighter, but I can't set the background colour.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scbtL.jpg) is wrong, how do I colour the empty background / white space, per file type not a global override?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Click Settings, Style Configurator.
2. In the right half of the pane for "Global Styles: Global override" click the color box next to background color to choose your color.
3. Check the box that says "enable global background color"

Comment: That will override it for all file types, is it possible to do it for only one?

Comment: I don't believe so.  This is the closest option for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 16):

While browsing for something similar myself, I've found a possible aid to this problem.

In the user-defined language style configuration menu (found under *Language > Define your language...*), you can right click the color panel, and it will become hatched. This allows it to simply use the default coloration for this section.

Unfortunately, I don't yet see a way to define a background color specific to a user-defined language.

Example:

[image: Screenshot link]

Credit for this solution comes from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/160925/adding-a-new-language-to-notepad) thread.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I've just stumbled on this after trying to setup a custom style for julia I found online. This was extremely helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @DavidPostill This is definitely the correct answer to fix one specific UDL in Notepad++, as requested. Brad's answer breaks Find result highlighting.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman The OP says "how do I colour the empty background / white space" **not** the font background colour!

Comment: Indeed. The "syntax highlighter" part threw me off.