# Notepad++ - Change colour for specific character

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible to change the colour for a specific character in Notepad++?
Let's assume you're using a defined language like KIXstart or Tex and you need every ";" in red colour.

Comment: Likely you could do that by defining the language yourself, if you cannot find a way to add KIXstart: https://superuser.com/questions/160925/adding-a-new-language-to-notepad, and see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574121/adding-a-user-defined-language-in-notepad

Answer (score 1):

You can use UDL (User Defined Language) to set up whatever syntax highlighting you want, by going ***Language*** > ***User Defined Language*** > ***Define your language...***.

For the example you gave, you'd do:

1. **Create new...** and give it a name ("red semicolons")
2. Go to the **Operators & Delimiters** tab and enter your operator `";"` in the ***Operators 1*** field
   [image]
3. Press the **Styler** button right on top of it and select red for the Foreground Color
   [image]
4. Then on your file, go to ***Language*** and select your new language (*red semicolons* from the bottom of the list

Or you can do the same by added an XML file (*red_colons.xml*) containing the style to the Notepad++ userDefineLangs directory (`%AppData%\Roaming\Notepad++\userDefineLangs`). Something like (the specific rule is in the `Keywords name="Operators1"` and style in `WordsStyle name="OPERATORS"`):

```
<NotepadPlus>
<UserLang name="red semicolons" ext="" udlVersion="2.1">
    <Settings>
        <Global caseIgnored="no" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="no" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
        <Prefix Keywords1="no" Keywords2="no" Keywords3="no" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="no" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="no" />
    </Settings>
    <KeywordLists>
        <Keywords name="Comments"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators1">&quot;;&quot;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords3"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords4"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords5"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords6"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords7"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords8"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Delimiters">00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
    </KeywordLists>
    <Styles>
        <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="7" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="7" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
    </Styles>
</UserLang>
```

Comment: Thank you, Yisroel and @DrMoishe for those tips... I'll try to apply them to the current language (Kix).